Can the number of elements of order 4 in the Tate–Shafarevich group grow arbitrarily large?
Let $E/K$ be a number field. For quadratic field extensions $L/K$, it is known that $\operatorname{Ш}(E/L)[2]$ can be arbitrarily large (cf. P. L. Clark and S. Sharif, "Period, index and potential Sha," Algebra and Number Theory 4, No. 2, 151–174, 2010).
What is known about elements of order 4? More specifically, for a quadratic extension $L/K$, can the number of order 4 elements in ${\operatorname{Ш}}(E/L)$ grow arbitrarily large, or is it bounded? If any results on this question are known, I would appreciate references.

ANT's landing page, the PDF itself, and MSN all think that the title of the Clark–Sharif paper is "Period, index and potential, III". However, the arXiv (and the content of the paper itself!) makes it clear that the title of the paper is supposed to be as you've said. What a strange gaffe by the publisher.

It follows from work of Alex Smith that the 4-Selmer rank can be arbitrarily small with the 8- Selmer rank vanishing and this implies the algebraic rank is 0 and hence the 4-Sha rank is large.

@Will Sawin  Thank you very much. I am having trouble identifying which reference and theorem number is relevant. I thought it might be Theorem 4.3 of arxiv.org/abs/1607.07860, is this the result you had in mind?

This follows from Theorem 1.5 of Alex Smith's paper "The distribution of $\ell^\infty$-Selmer groups in degree $\ell$ twist families I" which states

Suppose $A/\mathbb Q$ is an elliptic curve that fits into eitehr case (1) or (3) of Assumption (1.1). Given any nonicnreasing sequence $r_2 \geq r_4 \geq \dots \geq r_{2^k} \geq \dots$ of nonnegative integers, we have $$ \lim_{H \to\infty} \frac{ \# \{d \in \mathbb Z^{\neq 0} \colon |d|<H \textrm { and } r_{2^K} (A^d) = r_{2^k} \textrm{ for all }k\geq 1\}}{2H} = P^{\textrm{Alt}}(r_2\mid \infty) \cdot \prod_{k=2}^{\infty} P^{\textrm{Alt} }( r_{2^k} \mid r^{2^{k-1}})$$

Choose $r_2 = 2N$ for a large $N$, $r_4 =2N$, $r_8=0$, and thus $r_{2^k}=0$ for all $K>3$. The definition of $P^{\textrm{Alt}}(j\mid n))$ makes it clear that this probability is nonzero as long as $j$ and $n$ have the same parity and $1$ if $j=n=1$, and it can also be checked that $P^{\textrm{Alt}}(j\mid \infty))$ is nonzero for all nonnegative integers $j$, so the product on the right-hand side is zero. Hence the limit on the left-hand side is nonzero. In particular, the numerator on the left-hand side must be nonzero for some $H$, and therefore there exists a $d$ such that the $2$-Selmer rank $r_{2}$ of the quadratic twist $A^d$ is $2N$, the $4$-Selmer rank is $2N$, and the $8$-Selmer rank is $0$.
This implies the algebraic rank is $0$, and so the 4-Sha rank of the Tate-Shafarevich group is at least $2N-2$ (the loss of $2$ coming from the possible $2$-torsion of $A$, though we may choose $A$ to have no $2$-torsion).

Thank you for the wonderful answer. Let me ask one question - I think that the desired $d$ in this question (if it can be explicitly constructed) would need to be a product of many prime factors. Is there any information available about the number of prime factors that $d$ would have? For example, whether $d$ cannot be prime, etc.

@Duality There is a result of this form. It's something like "For each new prime factor of $d$, the $2$-Selmer rank can increase by at most $2$, so the number of prime factors must be at least half the difference between the desired rank and the rank of the initial curve" but I don't know the precise optimal statement.
